# Change a file's 'Date Last Modified' property via VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

How do I change the 'Date Last Modified Property' of a powerpoint file using VBA? I'm getting an error when trying to set f.FileDateModified at the bottom.  Here's what I have so far:

```
    Set oPresentation = Presentations.Open(sFolder & StrFile, , , False)
       Dim fso As Object
       Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       Dim oFile As Object
       Dim fileModDate As String
       Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       Set f = fs.GetFile(sFolder & StrFile)
       fileModDate = f.DateLastModified
       Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sFolder & StrFile & "meta.txt")
       oFile.WriteLine "Last author: " & oPresentation.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Last author")
       'oFile.WriteLine "Last save time: " & oPresentation.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Last save time")
       oFile.WriteLine "Date last modified " & fileModDate
       oFile.Close

       Call oPresentation.SaveAs(sFolder & StrFile & "x")
       Set f = Nothing
       Set fs = Nothing
       
       Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       Set f = fs.GetFile(sFolder & StrFile & "x")
       f.DateLastModified = fileModDate
       
       oPresentation.Close
       Set f = Nothing
       Set fs = Nothing
```

Comment: The `DateLastModified` Property is read-only... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/datelastmodified-property?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Wouldn't modifying and then saving the file do quite exactly that?

Comment: Darn you're right@Arod. @Mathieu, yes that's exactly what happens. I want to preserve the original Date last modified value and make that the new value after saving. Saving the file overwrites the date/time that I want to preserve.

Comment: @Gofurther Sounds like your attempt to sneakily change something will be futile!

Comment: Well I promise it's above board haha.

Comment: `DateLastModified` prop is read_only, but is there a way to modify it regardless?

Comment: If we're talking about pptx or pptm, that's Office Open XML. That's a zip file filled with XML files. Research that - the file formats are completely documented.

Comment: It's actually a collection of .ppt files. I convert them to .pptx but need to retain the metadata ie. `DateLastModified` of the .ppt files

Comment: For Windows, in C, you can use the `SetFileTime` function. I know there is a way to call it from VBA but can't remember quickly.

Answer (score 5):

This code sets a file's `ModifyDate` to the current date and time for any file which is closed. It doesn't work for open files, but doesn't give an error if the file is open.
I used VBA Word, but I guess that it also works for VBA PowerPoint.

```
Sub SetDateTime(Folder, FileName)
   Dim oFile As Object

   Set oFile = CreateObject("Shell.Application").Namespace(Folder).ParseName(FileName)
   oFile.ModifyDate = FormatDateTime(Date, 2) & " " & FormatDateTime(Time, 3)
   Set oFile = Nothing
 
End Sub
```

Another thing is the formatting of the date and the time. I use the function `FormatDateTime` with the option `2` and `3` respectively. Please note the space between the two.  Of course, the values of `Date` and `Time` can be changed to your needs.